# Blog for PHP, XHTML, CSS, jQuery and etc

Tags: php, jquery, css, xhtml, blogs

So, I am surfing around in the Google, using different keywords for finding a nice blog that would have great and exciting demos with how-to's about web design and programming. But efforts have no results, all I found were some old blogs.

I know one place that I visit oftenly: [www.tutsplus.com](http://www.tutsplus.com)
But this blog is has even too much stuff and also pretty much with exclusive content, to see you gotta pay.

My question is: "What blog's do you often visit to find some new cool stuff that can be easily implemented on your website?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this are pretty good blogs

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/

http://webdeveloperplus.com/

http://www.webappers.com/

http://www.position-absolute.com/

http://www.alistapart.com/

[25 Web Development Blogs You Should Be Reading](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/25-web-development-blogs-you-should-be-reading/)

Answer (score 2):

http://webdesignledger.com/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com

Those are my favorites. They often feature great jQuery plugins, blog themes etc. And other than that..

http://www.wordpress.org is always great for Wordpress blog news.

But really, what I like to do is snoop out new features on new blogs, and type in a more direct query (such as "How to implement Facebook LIKE Counter on your blog" and do the research). Once you know which feature/function you want to replicate, you'll get a better search result! :)